# Perl::Critic: "Code before warnings are enabled" when using -w

Tags: perl, perl-critic

Im getting "**Code before warnings are enabled**" from [Perl::Critic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl::Critic), even though I have `-w` specified in the shebang

> #!/usr/bin/perl -w

I really don't want to go through and replace all instances. Is there anything I can do? Additionally, I do want `Perl::Critic` to ensure all Perl has warnings enabled.

Comment: `perl -i~ -pe 's|#!/usr/bin/perl\K -w|\n\nuse warnings;|' *pl`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say `perlcritic` doesn't do what you want, but that you want it to do what you want. As such, you will need modify `perlcritic`, or more specifically, [Perl:: Critic:: Policy:: TestingAndDebugging:: RequireUseWarnings](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Perl::Critic::Policy::TestingAndDebugging::RequireUseWarnings). You should have no problems getting your changes accepted because the lack of shebang parsing is listed as a bug in the documentation.

---

It might be simpler to edit your files. It's quite trivial to do so mechanically. Assuming you already use `use strict;`,

```
find -type f \( -name '*.pl' -o -name '*.pm' \) ! -name '*~' -exec \
   perl -i~ -0777pe's/^(\s*)use strict\b.*\n\K/${1}use warnings;\n/mg' {} +
```